# Emploi du mot "panacée"

Tags: usage, grec

Peut-on employer couramment le mot "panacée" pour désigner :

> un remède remède prétendu universel contre tous les maux, capable de résoudre tous les problèmes

comme dans la phrase :

> Une panacée dans le domaine économique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je pense que "panacée" entre en effet dans le registre courant.

Toutefois, je l'ai pratiquement toujours entendu dans une tournure négative.

> Ce n'est pas la panacée

(probablement parce qu'il est plus probable de trouver une non-panacée qu'une panacée)

Answer (score 3):

Cette réponse arrive en complément des autres pour ajouter des précisions sur l'usage. La locution dans laquelle le mot « panacée » est le plus courant n'a jamais été « c'est pas la panacée » ou plutôt « ce n'est pas la panacée » mais « panacée universelle » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=panac%C3%A9e+universelle%2Cc%27est+pas+la+panac%C3%A9e%2Cn%27est+pas+la+panac%C3%A9e&corpus=19&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpanac%C3%A9e%20universelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27est%20pas%20la%20panac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpanac%C3%A9e%20universelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27est%20pas%20la%20panac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0)) ; l'utilisation croissant de « panacée » dans « n'est pas la panacée » n'est seulement devenu un peu plus importante qu'à la toute fin du 20ième siècle. Il est intéressant de noter que dans ces deux cas d'utilisation, le sens est souvent ironique.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panac%C3%A9e)) B. − P.ext., souvent iron.
>
> 1. [P.allus. à la polyvalence comme à l'efficacité attribuées à la panacée des alchimistes] Toute substance, tout procédé se révélant efficace dans le traitement d'un certain nombre de maladies.
>    --  Le docteur Saint-Ernest énumérait les maladies justiciables de sa méthode curative. Comme on le devine, rien ne se dérobait à l'action souveraine de cette panacée (Reybaud, J. Paturot, 1842, p.90).
>    **Panacée universelle** La saignée. C'est du reste en ce moment, chez les Anglais, le remède en faveur, la panacée universelle; ils l'emploient pour tout et pour rien (Las Cases, Mémor. Ste-Hélène, t.1, 1823, p.367).
>    -- Il n'entendait rien à la médecine et appliquait ce maudit émétique à tous les maux. C'était sa panacée universelle (Sand, Hist. vie, t.2, 1855, p.257).
> 2. [P.allus. à la seule notion d'efficacité] Remède
>    -- (...) Tes fioles d'électricité et des globules soulagent-ils au moins quelques malades? −Peuh! ils guérissent un peu mieux que les panacées du Codex, ce qui ne veut pas dire que leurs effets soient continus et sûrs... Huysmans, Là-bas, t.1, 1891, p.9.

*Additions suggérées par [user Reyedy](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43055/emploi-du-mot-panac%c3%a9e/43068?noredirect=1#comment87203_43068) dans un commentaire.*

Le terme « panacée universelle » n'est cependant plus considéré comme une locution judicieusement construite, et cela à juste titre si l'on choisit de s'en tenir aux  notions dictées par l'origine du mot « panacée ». Voici ce qu'en dit L'[Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-panacee-universelle).

> Le nom panakeia, formé à l’aide de pan, « tout », et akos, « remède », avait deux emplois en grec. Comme nom propre, il désignait Panacée, une des filles d’Esculape, le dieu de la médecine. Comme nom commun, il désignait un remède apte à soigner toutes les maladies, sens qu’a conservé la forme française panacée. On imagine bien la valeur d’un tel produit, ce qui explique que sa recherche fut, avec celle de la pierre philosophale et de l’élixir de vie éternelle, le souci constant des alchimistes. La panacée étant, comme son étymologie l’indique, un remède contre tous les maux, on évitera de lui adjoindre l’adjectif universelle, quand bien même ce tour se lirait chez de très bons auteurs comme Chateaubriand, Balzac, Eugène Sue, Claude Bernard, Las Cases ou George Sand, mais on choisira entre remède universel et panacée.

L'[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=panac%C3%A9e+universelle%2Cc%27est+pas+la+panac%C3%A9e%2Cn%27est+pas+la+panac%C3%A9e%2Cpas+la+panac%C3%A9e&corpus=19&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpanac%C3%A9e%20universelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27est%20pas%20la%20panac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20la%20panac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpanac%C3%A9e%20universelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cn%27est%20pas%20la%20panac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpas%20la%20panac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0) suivant, une variante de celui qui est suggéré par user Reyedy, peut avoir a certain intérêt pour qui voudrait rechercher ce sujet plus en détail.

[image]

Comment: Il est intéressant de noter que l'emploi de "panacée universelle" est un pléonasme, et est vu comme plusieurs organismes (projet Voltaire, Académie française...) comme un emploi fautif. Pour compléter cette réponse, voici un ngram que je trouve plus fidèle, en mettant le plus général "pas la panacée" en opposition avec "panacée universelle" : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+la+panac%C3%A9e%2C+panac%C3%A9e+universelle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3#

Comment: @Reyedy — Pas vraiment un pléonasme si l'on considère *l'usage familier* : une panacée pour faire tomber la fièvre + une panacée pour les maladies du foie + une panacée pour … + une panacée du monde économique + …  = "panacée universelle" (incorrect formellement, mais utilisé historiquement comme le montre la réponse de LPH, de plus elle recouvre ici différents domaines scientifiques) se transforme en *"remède* [racine grecque] *universel"* (définition officielle qui semble limitée à un seul domaine).

Comment: Merci pour la précision, je comprends ce point de vue bien que cet usage ne me soit pas naturel.

Comment: +1 Bien meilleure réponse que la mienne ; j'étais allé chercher sur ngram pour essayer d'appuyer mon idée que panacée était généralement utilisé dans un contexte ironique, mais je n'avais pas su trouver des résultats satisfaisants. Mais je reste persuadé qu'aujourd'hui, panacée a une connotation négative : que si jamais l'auteur essaye de vendre un produit extrêmement performant, qu'il sera bien mieux pris au sérieux en utilisant les mots "la solution à tous nos problème" voire "remède miracle" que "panacée" sans ironie.

Comment: On voit bien que *panacée* (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=30&year_end=2019&content=panac%C3%A9e+universelle%2C+panac%C3%A9e%2C+rem%C3%A8de+universel&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpanac%C3%A9e%20universelle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpanac%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crem%C3%A8de%20universel%3B%2Cc0) n'est plus [est peu] utilisée dans un contexte médical de nos jours (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22panac%C3%A9e%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2001,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_fr) mais que le concept dilue la puissance du remède en le transformant en solution …

Comment: …  Un remède soigne, une solution satisfait l'intellect. Les titres des livres correspondants aux deux autres ngram éclairent les réponses de cette question.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, c'est un terme d'origine médical qu'on emploie maintenant pour tout ce qui constitue un remède contre toute attaque.

Answer (score 1):

> Un remède prétendu universel contre tous les maux, capable de résoudre tous les problèmes.

On considère l'objet pour son aspect vertueux, du même genre que « [le multilatéralisme était une sorte de dogme, infaillible et vertueux](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/vertueux) » ou bien « [L'inversion de la courbe du chômage, le mantra de François Hollande](https://www.lexpress.fr/actualites/1/societe/l-inversion-de-la-courbe-du-chomage-le-mantra-de-francois-hollande_1309561.html) ». En fait, le mantra c'est une sorte de précepte, de leitmotiv.

L'expression « ce n'est pas la panacée » signifie généralement que l'on est pas satisfait du résultat produit par rapport aux qualités attribuées à l'objet.

Par glissement de sens, on obtient « c'est un mantra dans le domaine économique ».